# Dimensions of a Dashboard App

Tags: rally

I know an app can tell if its running in a dashboard or not (using rally.sdk.util.Context), but is there a way for it to know what the dimensions of the dashboard component is?

For example, how many pixels horizontal and vertical do I have to work with?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SDK 1.0 apps you can use underlying dojo methods to assist in your App creation.

If you want the current size of your App you can use:

```
dojo.window.getBox();
```

That will return you an object that looks like this:

```
{
   "w":1626,
   "h":372,
   "l":0,
   "t":0
}
```

If you want to read up on that function you can do so on dojo's docs [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dojo/window).

Comment: Great-- and is there a solution for Rally SDK 2.0?

Comment: In 2.0 you should be able to just do this.getSize() from your app class.  Since the app container is wrapped in a ViewPort with fit layout it should take up the entire available space.